# Visual Studio Project Template with Custom HTML Element Intellisense

Tags: html, visual-studio, intellisense, project-template

Is there a way to create a Visual Studio project template that provides Intellisense for custom HTML elements?  I know I can add the xsd to the commonHTML schema, but i'd prefer it only be available for my project type.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate .xsd file (dont change the existing one) and add it to the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html" folder.

Then copy and paste this to a .reg file (change `http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ctrls` to your own namespace), and run it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\Packages\{1B437D20-F8FE-11D2-A6AE-00104BCC7269}\Schemas\http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ctrls]
"File"="html\\your_file.xsd"
"Friendly Name"="Your Name"
"IsBrowseable"=dword:00000001
```

Then you can select it for your project in the drop down list with target schemas for validation.